# How to display the designer with user controls

Tags: user-controls, visual-c#-express-2010

I have added a User Control to my project. After having added it, I have extended it to the "tabPage" class (since I want it to be a tabPage):

```
public partial class userParPage : TabPage 
    {
    ...
    }
```

Since that moment the designer got a "strange" look. Here's a picture:

[image]

It doesn't matter where I place the label and the textbox, I am not able to change their size/position etc.

Does anyone know how to reset the normal designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a work-around.

1. Change the class from `tabPage` to `UserControl`. The Winform designer will display as usual;
2. Make your changes to the form;
3. When it's done, re-change the class from `UserControl` to `tabPage`.

Like this, you will be able to build up visually your custom user control and to give it a specific type (such as tabPage) just after.